# Int has no member multiplyReportingOverflow

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swiftsoup

I recently loaded tesseract for ios with cocoapods however now anywhere multiplyReportingOverflow is used within another pod file throws an error.

in attempts to fix this problem, I removed tesseract, which didn't work.

I created an empty project and loaded swiftsoup(pod with most errors) and the function is still not being recognized.

I have reinstalled cocoapods and cleaned all my caches and reinstalled all pods but I am still having no luck

Answer (score 0):

Update your SwiftSoup to latest version.
This error appears when you are using an old swif version, in this case with SwiftSoup.